# How do I interpret Joshua 10?

Tags: exegesis, bible, joshua

I know questions have been asked looking for scientific evidence; but let's set that aside.

If we are to interpret the bible, we must interpret it with scripture, no? This is why I will not accept scientific evidence, because you are using the science to interpret the bible.

So, how do we interpret Joshua 10's `So the sun stood still and the moon stopped`? What did joshua mean?
Could you say that:
1) The earth is not moving and at rest, while everything else revolved around the it.
2) This was a miracle. [I would need proof from within the text, not just an 'I think']
3) We dont know.

Comment: Welcome. It sounds like you are looking for an overview of explanations provided by those who believe that the Scriptures are inerrant.  That's important to include in your question, because some people who associate themselves with Christianity do not believe that.  When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Are you asking if the verse you quote should be taken to mean that the sun rotates around the earth? That the author of Joshua believed that the sun rotated around the earth? Are you asking if this was a miracle or a natural occurrence?

Comment: It clearly was a miracle, as there is no way for a natural occurrence to keep the sun still in the sky in the Middle East. As to what *kind* of miracle, that may be up for debate.

Comment: @warren: It's hardly clear to me that it was a miracle. What seems far more likely to me is that the text was never meant to be taken literally... It's clearly a quotation (it says as much in [black and white](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua+10&version=NIV)!) of poetry. There's no special reason to believe the poetry was describing literal events, rather than describing the mood of the situation.

Comment: @Flimzy - you are definitely the first person I've ever heard deny the miraculous nature of the event

Comment: @warren: I guess you haven't spent much time on google, then :)

Comment: @Flimzy - not on *this* topic, no :) ...but in 3+ decades of being in and around churches of several flavors, thousands of sermons, scores of books and commentaries, etc, this is definitely brand-new (from someone claiming to be a Christian - unbelievers, of course, deny most-to-all of the miracles described in the bible)

Comment: @warren: I suggest you do google it then. Seek Christian explanations for the verse (hint: google "Joshua 10 exegesis"). It sounds like you'll learn something. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know**

The only scriptural interpretation of that is that the Bible states that it happened. ESV Quote:

> The sun stopped in the midst of heaven and did not hurry to set for
>   about a whole day. 14 There has been no day like it before or since[...]

There have been plenty of guesses on how that miracle occurred, but it is all speculation. These include, but are not limited to:

- Some commentators say that God locked the entirety of the Universe in
  place, others say just the Earth stopped rotating.
- Still others say that this was caused by the planet's rotation was
  slowed, or that the earth continued to rotate, but there was an S-shaped wobble on the axis, so the sun did not actually set in that area (similar to
  a summer day in the far north). This is referencing the "did not hurry to set" verbage.
- Other state there was some sort of reflection or refraction so it
  only looked like the sun moved over that specific area.
- The scholar Robert Dick Wilson in 1920 translated the previous verses
  as "*Be eclipsed, O sun, in Gibeon, and thou moon in the valley of
  Aijalon! And the sun was eclipsed and the moon turned back*",
  indicating it was a ancient understanding of the rare and then-misunderstood solar eclipse as a sign from God, although the "*has been no day like it before or since...*" portion would then be referencing the 2nd half of the verse "...*when the Lord heeded the voice of a man, for the Lord fought for Israel*." This translation writes the entire miracle out of the text.
- Lastly, some believe that it was sheer perception and poetic license, that the Israelites simply vanquished their enemies with such incredible speed it was 'as though' the day had stood still. That view is undoubtedly based that they had no other ways to arbitrarily measure time outside of the position of celestial bodies, thus thinking that some sort of time dilation had occurred when it actually had not. This camp notes that Israel's enemies at the time, the Amorites, worshipped the sun and moon, and thus the incident was Jehovah's display of dominance over that region's deities.

This isn't the only reference to the God of Israel playing with time - time goes backwards for a bit with Hezekiah (reflected in 2nd Kings 20, Isaiah 38), which is also referenced in 2 Chronicles 32:31, where:

> envoys of the princes of Babylon, who had been sent to him to inquire
>   about the sign that had been done in the land

which many believe to reference the time reversal from 2nd Kings 20 and Isaiah 38.

There isn't any reference in the rest of the scripture, to my knowledge, of the Joshua incident; however, there is a passing illustration within a prayer in Habakkuk 3:11 that references the sun and moon standing still. Some have pointed to a similar story in Greek, Babylonian, Persian, Aztec, Incas, Chinese and Egyptian mythos, although approximate dates for those possibly-related miracles vary wildly, and are thought to be unrelated.